# Visual Studio: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: visual-studio, c#, dll

I've generated a DLL through Visual Studio (using C#), which I then call through a piece of software I'm using.

However I get the error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

The DLL is being loaded, and part of the code appears to run.

I should note that this doesn't work on older versions of the software, but does work on newer versions. The DLL I'm running references another DLL (which comes with each version of the software).

I've also tried playing around with the NET framework - however this doesn't appear to have done anything.

I'm a newbie when it comes to things like this, so any advice/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try attaching a debugger yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I have very little experience with C#, visual studio, etc. Therefore I really don't know how to attach a debugger.